# Get post id on click of thumbnail

Tags: posts, jquery, ajax, thumbnails

I am a little lost so I apologize if this question is vague and not organized well. I currently have a grid of thumbnails populated via Wordpress. I retrieve them by getting all the posts in a category and getting their thumbnails. I now want it so when you click on the thumbnails it pulls up the body of the post in a text box I have on the same page as the grid. I am looking for someone to point me in a direction as to how I get the post id when I click the post and then how I load the text box with the body text from that id.

GRID OF THUMBNAILS:

```
foreach  ( $categories as $category ) {
  $i = -1;
  echo '<div class="grid-row"><h2>' . $category->name . '</h2></div>';
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $category->term_id );
  $cat_posts = new WP_Query($args);
  if ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $i++;
    $cat_posts->the_post();
    $face = get_field( 'face' );
    $name = get_field( 'fullname' );
    if ( $i % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="grid-row">';
    echo '<div class="obj">';
    echo '<div class="faceThumb">';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($face);
    echo '</div><div class="name">' . $name . '</div></div>';
    if ( ($i % 6 == 5) || $i == ($cat_posts->post_count - 1) ) echo '</div>';
  endwhile; endif;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

***UPDATED FOR POST BELOW***
//index

```
        <div id="PersonBio">this is my bio</div>
          <div id="mainTextTitle">
                                      <?php the_title(); ?>

          </div>
              <div id="mainText">

                <ul class="faces">



<?php
$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=2' ); 

foreach  ( $categories as $category ) {
  $i = -1;
  echo '<div class="grid-row"><h2>' . $category->name . '</h2></div>';
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $category->term_id );
  $cat_posts = new WP_Query($args);
  if ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $i++;
    $cat_posts->the_post();
    $face = get_field( 'face' );
    $name = get_field( 'fullname' );
    if ( $i % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="grid-row">';
    echo '<div class="obj" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">';
    echo '<div class="faceThumb">';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($face);
    echo '</div><div class="name">' . $name . '</div></div>';
    if ( ($i % 6 == 5) || $i == ($cat_posts->post_count - 1) ) echo '</div>';
  endwhile; endif;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>    </ul>




  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

//functions

```
add_action('wp_ajax_select_face_post', 'select_face_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_select_face_post', 'select_face_post');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'faces_posts_scripts');

function select_face_post () {
  error_reporting(0);
  if ( ! isset($_POST['postid']) || ! intval($_POST['postid']) ) die();
  if ( ! isset($_POST['nonce']) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'],'postface') ) die();
  $post = get_post($_POST['postid']);
  if ( empty($post) || ! is_object($post) ) die();   
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode( $post );
  die();
}

function faces_posts_scripts() {
  // replace 'all_faces' with the slug of page in which resides the code you posted
  if ( is_page('team') ) { 
    wp_register_script( 'postface', get_template_directory_uri . 'Team/postface.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );     
    $url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('postface');
    wp_localize_script( 'postface', 'postface_vars', array('ajaxurl' => $url, 'nonce' => $nonce) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'postface' );
  }
}
```

//js

```
// postface.js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', 'div.obj', function() {
    var selectedpost = $(this).data('id');
    if ( selectedpost > 0) {
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postface_vars.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { action: 'select_face_post', nonce: postface_vars.nonce, postid: selectedpost }
       }).done( function(data) {
        if (data.post_content) {
          // var id =  data.ID;
          // var title = data.post_title;
          $('#PersonBio').html(data.post_content);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ajax.

### The html:

```
<div id="PersonBio"></div>
<div id="mainTextTitle"></div>

<div id="mainText">
  <ul class="faces">
  <?php
  $categories = get_categories();
  foreach  ( $categories as $category ) {
    $i = -1;
    echo '<div class="grid-row"><h2>' . $category->name . '</h2></div>';
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $category->term_id );
    $cat_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) :
      $i++;
      $cat_posts->the_post();
      $face = get_field( 'face' );
      $name = get_field( 'fullname' );
      if ( $i % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="grid-row">';
      echo '<div class="obj" data-id="' . get_the_ID() . '">';
      echo '<div class="faceThumb">';
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($face);
      echo '</div><div class="name">' . $name . '</div></div>';
      if ( ($i % 6 == 5) || $i == ($cat_posts->post_count - 1) ) echo '</div>';
    endwhile; endif;
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### In `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_select_face_post', 'select_face_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_select_face_post', 'select_face_post');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'faces_posts_scripts');

function select_face_post () {
  error_reporting(0);
  if ( ! isset($_POST['postid']) || ! intval($_POST['postid']) ) die();
  if ( ! isset($_POST['nonce']) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'],'postface') ) die();
  $post = get_post($_POST['postid']);
  $face = get_field( 'face',  $post->ID );
  $name = get_field( 'fullname',  $post->ID );
  $post->face_field = $face;
  $post->name_field = $name;
  if ( empty($post) || ! is_object($post) ) die();   
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode( $post );
  die();
}

function faces_posts_scripts() {
  if ( is_page('team') ) { 
    wp_register_script( 'postface', get_template_directory_uri() . '/Team/postface.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );     
    $url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('postface');
    wp_localize_script( 'postface', 'postface_vars', array('ajaxurl' => $url, 'nonce' => $nonce) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'postface' );
  }
}
```

### Then create a file called 'postface.js' and put there the following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', 'div.obj', function() {
    var selectedpost = $(this).data('id');
    if ( selectedpost > 0) {
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postface_vars.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { action: 'select_face_post', nonce: postface_vars.nonce, postid: selectedpost }
       }).done( function(data) {
        if (data) {
          // var id =  data.ID;
          $('#mainTextTitle').html(data.name_field);
          $('#PersonBio').html(data.face_field + data.post_content);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

### For info see:

- [This very useful Smashing Magazine tutorial](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)
- [Codex about ajax in wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)
- [Codex for wp_ajax_{action} hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29)
- [Codex for wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: I've tried to get this to work for a while now but can't get it. Would you mind looking above at the code.

Comment: @BDGapps not it works, there were 2 typo.

Comment: I still can't get it to work :(

Comment: I've tried this exactly code and works perfectly. Only things that I change are the two `get_field()` calls, because this function not exists in WP, so I think is your custom function. Is possible that you are not calling `wp_head()` in your html `<head>` and/or `wp_footer()` before the end of html `<body>`? Look at it, and if they are, copy the entire html output (what you see doing 'view source' in the browser) and paste it in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and give me the link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tNbfEHYC

Comment: Sorry, this is not the html output, this is your code. Open the 'team' page in Firefox or Chrome, than click CTRL+U and copy-paste everything appear on pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/833fx7eg

Comment: As I had guessed in a comment above, you don't have `wp_head();` before the closing html tag `</head>` and `wp_footer();` before the closing html tag `</body>`. These are **must-have** functions for **all** themes: a lot of plugins (sure all plugins that need js and/or css on frontend) rely on these functions. the same for lot of scripts you can find on the web, all of them assume that these functions are in the theme and not work if they aren't. See Codex for them [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer)

Comment: So it works but how do I get it to use my custom fields?    $face = get_field( 'face' );
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($face);

Comment: On second thought how do I just get the thumbnail image for a div?

Comment: I've edited the code to retrieve and use your custom fields.